# Using Integer.parseInt() Properly

Tags: android, android-activity, integer

I imported a string from another activity, which i want to change into an int.

```
        Bundle gotBasket = getIntent().getExtras();
        Integer.parseInt(gotBasket.getString("lol"));
```

From what i've read, the above code is how to do it. However, i don't know what "key", variablename or whatsoever, i will have to use, when using my integer.

For example if i have a TextView, and i want to set it to the value of the integer
I would say

```
 TextView.setText(???????????)
```

As you can see, i don't know what to write in that field, would love if someone could tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it.

```
try
{
    int a = Integer.parseInt(gotBasket.getString("lol"));
    textView.setText("" + a);
}
catch (NumberFormatException e)
{
    // handle the exception
}
```

Comment: Well, wouldn't that just create an int named a with the value '5'?

Comment: i put 5 as a placeholder until i copied the actual value :P it was supposed to show you that to set an integer value on a text field you need to do ""+a instead of simply a cause that would be interpreted as a resource id.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing the conversion right, but you're not saving the value anywhere.

```
int lulz = Integer.parseInt(gotBasket.getString("lol"));
```

Also, why do you want to convert it to an int to display it in a TextView?

Comment: Because i'm having a few buttons which needs to influence the value of the textview onclick, and you can't influence the value of a string, can you?

Comment: I tried doing what you mentioned, it gives me a java.lang.runetimeexception (resources$NotFoundException)